# Learning Mathematics using only audio.

Tags: soft-question, education

Are there any mathematics audio books or other audio sources for learning mathematics, like for example math podcasts which really go into detail. I ask this because I make about 1 hour from my house to the school and staring at a screen on the car makes me dizzy. I know about podcasts and stuff but those don't really teach you math, they talk about math news and mathematicians.

I ask this because many topics can be understood just by giving it a lot of thought and don't necessarily require pen and paper.

Regards.

Comment: I'm interested in this myself: I've always thought about how much I could be learning when driving.

Comment: I really hope you don't intend to drive **and** listen mathematics with headphones or stuff...and even less in Mexico City!

Comment: @AndrewSalmon, perhaps not that much if you're involved in an accident. Anything that takes attention away from the street is usually very dangerous for a driver...and for other drivers, and walkers and...

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, maybe I can listen to them in my sleep, like in *Fahrenheit 451*.

Comment: It is a good question for commuters using mass transit! (Personally, I cannot read in a moving vehicle, if I don't want to get sick!!)

Comment: @Andrew: Do you mean *Brave New World*?

Comment: @DonAntonio People in mexico city don't drive that bad, anyways I don't drive I go on the school bus so I don't put my or others safety at risk.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, Jorge: I'm mexican and from the D.F., and we all *there* are pretty reckless drivers. Anyway, if you commute without driving then it may be a good idea.

Comment: @DonAntonio Do yo think I could ask you some questions about studying mathematics in Mexcico?

Comment: You can try, Jorge, though all my superior studied I did abroad, not in Mexico.

Comment: Where did you do your supperior studies?

Comment: I actually did some online research at some point on how can mathematical expressions be read. Most of what I found was for accesibility of people with hearing difficulty, but I was interested for the same reason as you. Turns out, there isn't much at all, but did found some people that made a program that automatically generated speech from math in a certain format.

Comment: Does papers out loud exist? I couldn't find it on a Google search

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea for a podcast! Out of curiosity what level of Mathematics were you hoping to start at? (e.g. Alegebra, Calculus, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to narrow down topics you would like to learn and find YouTube videos of them, then download those YouTube videos listen to them during your commute. 
I have a daily two hour bus commute and use youtube video's audio to reinforce topics i'm learning at school.

For example: Lets say you want to review calculus, listen to this video on repeat for an hour (its 20 minutes long so you could get through it 3 times!)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=di_bzYD0Mkg

Comment: I think talking that fast doesn't leave room for you to think about it

Answer (score 3):

I can't really point to a source, but I find the question quite relevant, as audiobooks of mathematic subject can be important also for blind people.

[Learnoutloud](http://www.learnoutloud.com/Catalog/Science/Mathematics) has a repository of audiobooks and podcast about math and statistics, and related novels as well. Nevertheless it seems to offer no advanced math repository.

PapersOutLoud may be a good project.

Comment: I agree with papers out loud being a good Project. Learn out loud however, doesn't have a lot of stuff on math.

Comment: Half of what is on the website on "Math" is just novels. And the real courses only cover really basic stuff.

Comment: Yep, it seems that they spent much effort for braille book more than for audiobook. There is, probably, a reason. Anyhow that's what I found...

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Lectures Audio Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCinL2aecouDC89MiH40xxJg) channel in YouTube. I come across it with the video [The Interaction Between Category Theory and Set Theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTWe5b13M80).